# Does Google Authenticator track user data

Tags: security, google-authenticator, totp, google-2fa

I'm considering authentication option and wondered if Google accumulates user data from Google Authenticator?
App side?  Server side?
If so, anyone know what data this is?

Answer (score 0):

The open-source version of Google Authenticator is available here:
[Github link](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator).

Which doesn't include any sort of user-data collection as from what I verified. You can check for yourself.
However, the updated app which is served nowadays in the App/Play Store is an updated closed-sourced and we cannot tell if any user data collection is happening behind the scenes.

I assume Google's products are GDPR-compliant, so you can ask them directly what data are they collecting about you regarding this app. You can also ask them to delete any data collected within this app and they must comply.

I would also look at the privacy policy of the application.